# jquery event not firing for html generated from jquery template

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-templates

I am a bit new to Jquery and having this problem.

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input.selected").change(function () {

        var cbid = $(this).attr('id');

        var id = cbid.substring(3);

        var base = window.location.host;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/api/SPChoices/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Choice succesfully saved.");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("This user cannot be added.");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Delete",
                url: "/api/SPChoices/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Choice succesfully removed." + data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("This user cannot be deleted");
                }
            });

        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/api/SPChoices",
        data: "{'Count':'7'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            ApplyTemplate(msg);
        }
    });



});
```

while apply template generate html of codes. which is generating correctly.

```
function ApplyTemplate(msg) {

    $("#HBsTemplate").tmpl(msg).appendTo("#Container");

}

</script>

<script id="HBsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
<div>
            <div style=" float:left">
            <img id="imgChooseHBpp" src="/Images/2.png" alt="alt text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>${HostedBuyer.Name}</h3>
                <p>templ</p>
                <input class='selected' type='checkbox' {{if IsSelected}}         checked="yes" {{/if}}   id='cb_${HostedBuyer.id}' />
            </div>
</div>
</script>
```

My problem is the changing the check box does not trigger the events.

It works correctly if I generate the above html in razor on the server but not when I generate in at client like above?

What am I missing ?? please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality must be used in order to hook up events that do not occur at load-time.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand.

Comment: *$().change* works on EXISTING elements. *$().on* works with all elements, even dynamically loaded ones, which is the case with your templating system.

Comment: Right now your answer is only half-correct. `.on()` combines both delegate-style events and normal events. It depends on the arguments.

Comment: even $().on works only for already generated markup but not for the controls generated dynamically.

I have solved the problem by putting onchange="changefunction(event)
for in the template markup.
Thank you all for your answers.